# Meaning of (AppDelegate *)

Tags: objective-c, ios, syntax

Can someone explain what `(AppDelegate *)` in the following snippet means?

```
(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] iPad]
```

Comment: Missing a bracket: you probably mean `[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] iPad]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` returns an `id`. So you can't access e.g. `window` property of it (because id object doesn't have it).

`(AppDelegate *)` statement causes to 'convert' `id` to `AppDelegate` object, so you can access its components.

It's like having `NSObject *obj1;` and `NSString *obj2;` - you can't do `-substringToIndex:` with `obj1`...

Comment: The `delegate` method returns `id`, not `NSObject`.

Answer (score 3):

That code is casting the return value of `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` to the type `AppDelegate *`.

This is not strictly necessary, but it will prevent compiler warnings when you call the method `iPad` on a class that *may* not support that method call. Assuming, of course, that `AppDelegate` has a method called `iPad`.

Answer (score 2):

The delegate method returns an id (an unclassed object), so the compiler has no information about the object returned, and in particular doesn't know whether it has an iPad method. This is okay, but it leaves things sort of vague (dynamic typing). By casting the returned object explicitly to the AppDelegate class, you're telling the compiler that *you* know that the returned delegate object is an AppDelegate instance. This allows the compiler to check that your AppDelegate class does have an iPad method (static typing). This is good, because now the compiler can do more accurate error-checking. The compiler just believes your cast, though, so don't lie! If you do lie, and send the `iPad` message to an object that does *not* have an iPad method, your app can crash at runtime.

Comment: Of course, the O.P. *might* be asking about the meaning of asterisk in `AppDelegate*`. In that case, the answer is: when you send a message directly to a class you can use the bare class name (as in `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`), but when you state the type of an instance using a class name, e.g. to declare a variable or to cast (as here), you add the asterisk because classes are C pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply the class, and is used to cast the delegate to `AppDelegate`

Comment: So it is just casting whatever the method iPad returns to a class called AppDelegate?

Comment: It's casting whatever object the method returns to an instance of AppDelegate, yes.